# React does not show Image even complied successfully - Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

So I would like to use a Image in my React Project, but when I open the browser in order to view my website I am always getting a 404:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import img from "./App/assets/image.png";

ReactDOM.render(
  <img src={img} alt="img"></img>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

this is my webpack.config.js file:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
   mode: 'development',
   entry: './src/index.js',
   output:{
      path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/'),
      filename: 'bundle.js'
   },
   module: {
      rules: [
         {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/i,
            use: [
               'file-loader'
            //   {
            //     loader: 'file-loader',
            //    //  options:{
            //    //     name: '[name].[ext]',
            //    //     outputPath: 'assets',
            //    //  }
            //   },
            ],
          },
         {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: { presets: ["@babel/env"] }
          },
      ]
   },
   devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: true,
      contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public/"),
      port: 3000,
      publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/dist/",
      hotOnly: true
    },
};
```

the .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

After that it compiles successfully but the browser-console shows:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/da8ab57a5dacdcc560a4f73bd6e235a8.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: In my webpack I don't have file-loader for images but url-loader and it works. https://webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader/

Comment: @bubulledu93 - thank you for your comment but it still shows the same error. It is so weird because webpack always compiles successfully.